# what's the easiest way to get JSON objects from jQuery into .net?

Tags: jquery, wcf, json

I'm working on an asp.net/jQuery app that needs to communicate to the server.

The page features a series of checkboxes, and I would like to configure jQuery to tell the server a simple message like this

"checkBox ID 12 is checked"

That will turn into simple Json

```
{
     "ID": "12",
     "Checked" : "true"
}
```

I don't think I need to get into RIA Services, at least I hope not. All I want to do is keep a record of what has been checked on the server in case they close the browser and come back later.

What is the best technique to achieve this with minimal code? WCF?

Thanks,
John

Comment: From the client-side, you would just issue either a [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or a [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call and configure the parameters to those functions to pass the data you want to your server.

Comment: @jfriend00, that's true of MVC is it true of webforms too?

Comment: @kenny - I don't understand your question.  The OP is talking about keep the server informed about the state of a checkbox.  It doesn't matter if that checkbox is in a form or not.  If this is to be done without the use explicitly submitting a form, then it probably needs to be done using ajax and the server (no matter what architecture it's using) has to be able to process that ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00, I guess my point is that ASP.NET WebForms makes processing posts from Javascript straight forward, I"m wondering since I don't use it often. I know in the ASP.NET MVC that it's well supported and almost automatic the processing of a JSON class to a MVC method.

Comment: I was thinking of using jQuery.ajax on the client side, but what about the server side? WCF is hugely complex, and might be overkill for such a simple service. Asp.net ajax is probably not here to stay, so I want to move to something more permanent.

Answer (score 1):

ASMX ScriptServices (or ASPX's page methods if you want to keep this code with a particular page's code) are a great way to do that without succumbing to WCF's complexity. If you use jQuery's `$.ajax()` to send JSON from the client-side that matches a class on the server-side, ASP.NET will handle the mapping between JSON and that object automatically: http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

In fact, if you end up needing to deal with DateTimes, Dictionaries, or enums in JSON, ASMX's underlying serializer is *better* than WCF's.

In the long run, [Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) is going to hit the sweet spot between ASMX's simplicity and WCF's additional features. In my experimentation, moving an ASMX service to Web API is extremely easy though. So, you can take the easy option today and not worry about painting yourself into a corner if ASMX is deprecated in ASP.NET 5 (however, ASMX is *still* in the Add New Item list as "Web Service" in the Visual Studio v.Next developer preview, so you really have to take talk about its imminent deprecation with a grain of salt).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your webpage is created...I have recently created a page that was dynamically driven and I pass in a JSON string representation of the JSON object in the background, and then on page load take that JSON string and turn it into a JSON object.  Then when the user makes changes, in the background, I then manipulate that JSON object and send it to the server and pass it along from there.

I guess you could create a JSON object on the fly, whenever the a checkbox is selected and then make an ajax call via jquery.  Now each time you select a checkbox does that need to add to the JSON object or create its own individual object?

Why do you need a JSON object if your just wanting to tell the server that an object has been selected?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I want to use jQuery on the client side, but what about the server side? Is WCF the best way to create a service that accepts json objects?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way was to use a combination of jQuery $.post() and a generic handler that pulls the values out of the Request.Form collection, so I don't need to get involved in WCF at all.